# Getting information from one class method to another

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, dask, class-method

I am trying to make a bunch of class methods to read specific parts of .JSON files and am having trouble getting info through from one method to another, in this particular case I'm trying to get the dask.bag from the 'read_files' method over to the 'split_to_requests' method. I'm not sure where my mistake is, but running unit tests fails on the 'test_split_requests' test. I added tests on the bottom of the code.

```
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    from dask import bag

    class WeatherDataConverter:

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(WeatherDataConverter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.meteo_bag = bag.Bag

        def read_files(self, files):
            dask_bag = bag.read_text(files).map(json.loads)
            return dask_bag

        def split_to_requests(self, dask_bag):
            data_pluck = dask_bag.flatten().pluck('data')
            request_request = data_pluck.pluck('requests')
            return request_request

        @staticmethod
        def flatten(bag):
            print(bag)
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    from unittest import TestCase
    from weather.WeatherDataConverter import WeatherDataConverter


    class TestWeatherDataConverter(TestCase):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(TestWeatherDataConverter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.converter = WeatherDataConverter()

        def test_read_file(self):
            dask_bag = self.converter.read_files('../data/*.json')
            assert dask_bag.count().compute() == 5

        def test_split_requests(self):
            dask_bag = self.converter.read_files('../data/*.json')
            dataframe = dask_bag.split_to_requests()
            print(dataframe)
```

this is the fail code:

```
    test_weatherDataConverter.py:35                 
    (TestWeatherDataConverter.test_split_requests)
    self = <tests.weather.test_weatherDataConverter.TestWeatherDataConverter         
    testMethod=test_split_requests>

        def test_split_requests(self):
            dask_bag = self.converter.read_files('../data/*.json')
    >       dataframe = dask_bag.split_to_requests()
    E       AttributeError: 'Bag' object has no attribute 
    'split_to_requests'

    test_weatherDataConverter.py:38: AttributeError

    Assertion failed
```

Comment: You are trying to call `WeatherDataConverter.flatten` but your class `WeatherDataConverter` doesn't have a method `flatten`.

Comment: @Heike yes, that is one of the mistakes, I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up finding an answer myself, so if anyone feels there is a better way feel free to comment on this, maybe this will help anyone.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from dask import bag

class WeatherDataConverter:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WeatherDataConverter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.meteo_bag = bag.Bag

    def read_files(self, files):
        dask_bag = bag.read_text(files).map(json.loads)
        return dask_bag

    def convert(self, files):
    data = self.read_files(files).flatten().pluck('data')
    return data

    @staticmethod
    def flatten(bag):
        print(bag)
```